# Unable to get pickerView.tag in -pickerView:accessibilityLabelForComponent: method

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

#### Protocol:

`UIPickerViewAccessibilityDelegate`

#### Method:

`-pickerView:accessibilityLabelForComponent:`

#### Problem:

Apple Documentation says

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
accessibilityLabelForComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

But the pickerView which I get inside this method
is NOT a UIPickerView*,
but is a UIAccessibilityPickerElement,
and hence using pickerView.tag inside this method crashes.

I have 2 pickerviews in my view controller and I need to access the tag to identify them.

#### Question:

How can I provide accessibilityLabel for components of both pickerViews in this method?

Comment: I was about to post my own question about this sort of thing. I usually test method pickerViews against my ViewController's outlet properties that I've linked up against the specific pickerViews in my storyboard. Same as testing against tags i guess but as you said the pickerView you're passed is the UIAccessibilityPickerElement. In the debugger you can see that it has a pickerView property which matches what I'd expect. This is private API though so it's not like we can even cast the pickerView to this type. I'm going to log a bug about it

Comment: posted a radar bug 21345299 about this issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help.

I have a very similar problem with a custom component. I have a pickerView in this component. My was "weak" that's why I couldn't access to tag property.

I had to define a new property to identify each picker.